# XlsLib integration in IOS Application

Tags: ios, iphone, excel, xlslib

I'm trying to integrate [xlslib](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/) in my app. After compiling and installing lib, I have added this in my code. Then I got the error shown below:

```
format_t::format_t(CGlobalRecords& gRecords, const u16string& fmtstr) :
formatstr(fmtstr),
index(0),
m_usage_counter(0),
m_GlobalRecords(gRecords)
{
}
```

Errors:

`format.cpp:125:52: Reference to 'u16string' is ambiguous`

`Out-of-line definition of 'format_t' does not match any declaration in`

`xlslib_core::format_t`

while in format.h file, declaration as below

`format_t(CGlobalRecords& gRecords, const u16string& fmtstr);`

Can any one help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you post a bug report on the SourceForge page? In any case, the xlslib project has been updated and now offers the DHxlslibIOS library that you can incorporate as is into your project. You can download a zipped package [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/files/) with the latest 2.4.0b1 source, or pull it from SVN. The framework is in the DHxls directory.